# Can anyone suggest me site for PGM images for stereo vision?

Tags: image, pgm

I need some sample images for my project in stereo vision, please suggest some links where i can find `.pgm` gray scale images of good quality of both left and right vision (above 500KB size). Actually i googled it for many times but couldn't  find any thats why asking....

Comment: Why not make some? Take a camera, shoot a scene, move 6 inches to the left, take another one.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [CVLAB EPFL Datasets](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/data/index.php), and more precisely [Stereo face database](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/data/stereoface/) and [Multi view stereo](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/data/strechamvs/).

*That being said, [Computer Vision Online](http://www.computervisiononline.com/datasets) and the [Visual Geometry Group](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/) are good places to find vision datasets.*